# A probabilistic (exponential?) inference formula that I don't understand how to implement

Tags: algorithm, formula, exponential, probability-theory

I'm trying to implement a truth discovery algorithm from an academic paper. It is a streaming algorithm that infers the truth as well as source quality in real time. More details here if anyone is interested in reading the paper: http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2661892

My problem is that I don't understand a formula in the algorithm, or to be precise notation of one of the formulas and I'm having difficulties in implementing it in R or Python. It seems to be an exponential formula of some kind, but I haven't found anything about it in math books. Not sure about the half infinity sign as well. I assume it means proportional to, but does this mean value assignment, or what? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Just now noticed that I had accidentally cut out the upper part of the formula. The character on top of the capital-sigma is 1.

Comment: Half infinity???? It looks like an **alpha** to me.

Comment: The symbol stands for proportionality, indeed. But I cannot say what this means in the given context. Usually you define some proportionality when you don't care about the absolute value but e.g. only about the minimizer of a function. It does not really make sense for a scalar. I would probably just take it as = and see where it goes.

Comment: Oh, and the `exp(...)` means `e raised to the power of ...`, where `e` is the Euler number.

Comment: Thank you Nico, I will try both of your suggestions. How would you approach the subscript with multiple variables (like o) - i guess there should be a unique value for o each different subscript variable.

Comment: I just followed the posting rules, which said that everything related to algorithm implementation should be posted here. I'm still looking for comments on the proportionality part and how to implement that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(You really should have posted on Math or Computer Science; you are trying to understand the algorithm itself, not the algorithm's implementation. One big disadvantage is that Stack Overflow does not allow LaTeX, so pardon the hard-to-read stuff below.)

To be able to use the "proportional to" symbol \propto, you need to take into account that the left-hand side of the expression is a probability.

You can use the following as the "definition" of \propto:

P(X = x) \propto f(x)  <=>  P(X = x) = f(x)/(\sum_{x'} f(x'))

that is to say, P(X = x) is proportional to f(x), when normalized by the sum of f(x') for all values x' of random variable X.

For example, if an urn contains 10 blue balls and 20 red balls, the probability of drawing a ball of a given color is proportional to the number of balls of that color. Since the sum of probabilities needs to be 1, this means normalizing them in the following way:

P(Color = blue) \propto 10

P(Color = red)  \propto 20

P(Color = blue) = 10/(10 + 20) = 1/3

P(Color = red)  = 20/(10 + 20) = 2/3.

Now, in the paper you are working with, they are using a very compact notation \nu^t_{i,v,j} for the random variable and its value. Without knowing the rest of the paper, I am taking a guess that \nu^t_{i,v,j} stands for P(R^t_{i,j} = v), that is, the indices t, i and j indicate which random variable R^t_{i,j} is being talked about (they don't explicitly name the random variable there, so I am just using the name R here for clarity), whereas the index v represents the *value* of that random variable. However, it's better that you check I am correct in the assumption that the index v represents the value.

If that assumption is correct, then this expression means

\nu^t_{i,v,j} = f(v) / sum_v' f(v')

where f represents the right-hand side of the expression.

Naturally, the more efficient way of computing that is, for each t, i, j, to compute f(v) for each value v and store it in an array indexed in v, accumulate their sum as you go, and afterward simply divide each value in the array by the final sum.